# The cutest species problem

Tags: riddle, word

You travel far and wide in search of the one named 'the oracle'. You wish to ask a question which has been troubling you for days now. You trek through mountains and ice-caps, forests and cities and eventually find the oracle sitting motionless in a cave. You finally can find out your answer...

You look up at the oracle and ask:

"What is the cutest species currently alive on this planet?"

The oracle stirs and hands you a sheet which is shown below. He merely states:

"Solve the puzzle and you will know"

Here is the puzzle the oracle gave you:

---

Q1. Left 1.   My mouth is a city, all of my kind are full of floating trees
Q2. Left 1.   As humans are to the galaxy, dust is to humans
Q3. Right 1.  A dirty kick in football is the same as a woodcutter cutting a log and someone logging into someone else's account
Q4. Left 1.    I am oil in the sea, chemicals on the lab floor, and water down your shirt
Q5. Left 1.    If I move up at the start I will be considered rude, but at the end, you will set me rolling

[image: Grid]

> What does the oracle think the cutest species is?
>   Solve the puzzle by placing each answer horizontally in each row with the corresponding number. The answer will read downwards diagonally in the shaded boxes

Who can solve the cutest species problem?

**EDIT**

> Added a extra clue to Q3.

And because people are getting confused about 'left 1' and 'right 1' here is a hint:

> left and right are **Directions** and the 1 is **the amount** of the direction. Basically move all the letters (**Directions** by **the amount**)

This will help especially when you have the answers and are trying to fit them in the grid

Comment: Should I add the cryptic-crossword tag for this? It is kind of a crossword...

Comment: Some advice for choosing tags: looks at the [list of popular tags](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags?page=1&tab=popular), and see if any of their descriptions match your puzzle. In your case, the clues are riddles, the answer is a single word, and you haven't fully said what needs to be done, making this somewhat an enigmatic puzzle. Avoid making up new tags.

Comment: Thanks :) Didn't actually know there was a list

Comment: @MikeEarnest Edited so it is clearer what you must do

Comment: No problem, looks like a cool puzzle!

Comment: @Joe: For future reference, a cryptic crossword is a specific type of crossword where all the clues involve wordplay and regular definitions. Both [cryptic-crossword] and [cryptic-clues] are meant to refer to that. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptic_crossword

Comment: What do the left 1 and right 1 s mean?

Comment: @G-man and all others interested. The 'left 1' or 'right 1' part is to do with shunting the letters after you have got the answer. Who knows, it might even create another word...    :P

Comment: In my mind, oracle always appears as a "she". I don't know why.

Comment: I'm confused. "Cat" does not have five letters.

Comment: See my edit please

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My mouth is a city, all of my kind are full of floating trees

> Portsmouth... see Ports and Mouth :). So the word is ports since the mouth is Portsmouth while the trees are the boats since they float in water at ports. Ports become Sport. Letter: S

As humans are to the galaxy, dust is to humans

> Small, humans are small compared to the galaxy like how dust is small compared to humans. Or alternatively, SPECK. Now with a shift, we have: malls/pecks. They are both reasonable words though pecks is more related to an animal than malls. Letter: E

A dirty kick in football is the same as a woodcutter cutting a log and someone logging into someone else's account

> Nice job hacking. The word is hacks, which is turned into shacks. Letter: A

I am oil in the sea, chemicals on the lab floor, and water down your shirt

> Stain/Spill, as oil spills, spilled chemicals, and of course spilled water is a stain to the respective object. With a shift to the left one, we get: tains/pills. Pills is an actual word so that is probably the right one. Letter: L

If I move up at the start I will be considered rude, but at the end, you will set me rolling

> To slink means to sneak, or in this case sneak up at the start, which is quite rude. But of course, at the end, the person slinking will be running at fast as they can as they have been caught. Slink becomes links so our final letter is: S 
>  Or you could also use the free answer shown in the comment by the OP: @PythonMaster for all except the last letter. It is so much simpler than everyone thinks, UP at the START = rude. But UP at the end will START it. Or START-UP. So the word is literally in the question, just minus the ups. The word us start which turns into tarts. Yummy!

So we have:

> SEALS, Which must be seals.

Comment: I don't think you're right on Q2. there aren't any five letter animals with M in the second letter spot

Comment: You've left out the "left 1" part of the clue.

Comment: I was assuming "left 1" was the direction of the answer in the answer grid

Comment: No @Slepz, you must move everything along Left 1 space

Comment: Check the question  again I have added an edit - it will help

Comment: I had SPECK for 2 as well. HACK seems a good fit for 3, assuming it doesn't have to be 5 letters, giving A for a 3rd letter. Possibly leading to SEALS as the final solution (though the pluralisation makes it a little questionable).

Comment: @Alconja bang on!  Give me the clues and you get the accept

Comment: Is my answer right?

Comment: @PythonMaster for all except the last letter. It is so much simpler than everyone thinks, UP at the START = rude. But UP at the end will START it. Or START-UP. So the word is literally in the question, just minus the ups.

Comment: Add this and I can accept

Comment: Well done! :) I'll accept

Answer (score 5):

Q1. Left 1. My mouth is a city, all of my kind are full of floating trees

> I don't have this yet

Q2. Left 1. As humans are to the galaxy, dust is to humans

> Speck --> Pecks

Q3. Right 1. A dirty kick in football is the same as a woodcutter cutting a log and someone logging into someone else's account

> Hacks --> Shack

Q4. Left 1. I am oil in the sea, chemicals on the lab floor, and water down your shirt

> Spill -> Pills

Q5. Left 1. If I move up at the start I will be considered rude, but at the end, you will set me rolling

> Don't have it yet

Making the grid

> ?????
> PECKS
> SHACK
> PILLS
> ?????

Making the animal

> ?EAL? - perhaps SEALS? Using S at beginning and end of clue words is a definite pattern here, and one that makes the left/right thing easier.

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer based on the previous ones :

Q1. Left 1. My mouth is a city, all of my kind are full of floating trees

> Ports/Sport : Portsmouth is a city. Boats are floating trees

Q2. Left 1. As humans are to the galaxy, dust is to humans

> Speck/Pecks

Q3. Right 1. A dirty kick in football is the same as a woodcutter cutting a log and someone logging into someone else's account

> Hacks/Shack

Q4. Left 1. I am oil in the sea, chemicals on the lab floor, and water down your shirt

> Spill/Pills

Q5. Left 1. If I move up at the start I will be considered rude, but at the end, you will set me rolling

> Still looking...

Giving :

> SPORT
>  PECKS
>  SHACK
>  PILLS
>  ?????
>
> Still going for SEALS...

---

**EDIT**

Here's the script I used for the first and last question to get five letters word matching the swapping letter requirement :

```
# RUBY
a = ["word1", "word2", "word3"]
z = []
a.each do |b|
    w = b[1..4] + b[0] # for Q5 || w = b[-1] + b[0..3] for Q1
    if a.find_index(w) != nil
        z.push(b)
    end
end
puts z
```

I used this source for common 5 letters english words : http://www.poslarchive.com/math/scrabble/lists/common-5.html

Giving these lists of words :

- Q1 : http://pastebin.com/Aa1dBmQy
- Q5 : http://pastebin.com/ciQmsV9u

Comment: So close! think about this... the last word in the grid needs to end in 's' so the answer to the question must start with 's'...

Comment: @JoeBeastlyGerbil I edited my answer to show how I'm taking this problem, but I can't find (for now) a word matching Q5 clues...

Comment: Keep trying you'll get it

Comment: @JoeBeastlyGerbil I suppose the Q5 hint is referring to an idiom with "[sth] rolling" and/or "[sth] getting a head start", but not being a native english speaker, I can't seem to match any word. As a final hint, would you be so kind as to tell me if the word is in fact in the list I provided (words beginning by "S" in the pastebin for Q5)?